# Problems with return values of function pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have the following SSCCE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define streq(x, y) (strcmp((x), (y)) == 0)
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

typedef struct
{
    const char *cmd;
    void* (*fn)(void);
} __attribute__((__packed__)) Command;

void* getTime(void)
{
    return ((void*)((uintptr_t)time(NULL)));
}

void* getDay(void)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    return ((void*)((uintptr_t)(tm.tm_wday)));
}

static Command commands[] =
{
    {"time", getTime},
    {"day", getDay},
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(commands); ++i)
    {
        Command *p = commands+i;
        if (streq(argv[1], p->cmd)) printf("%d\n", (int)p->fn);
    }
}
```

My question is why when I run the code as such:

```
./test day
```

The return value is `3648` and not a value from 0-6 as specified [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *call* the function. Right now you're just printing the function pointer value. The following code should do it:

```
if (streq(argv[1], p->cmd)) printf("%d\n", (int)(p->fn()));
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking.  Thank you!